# Apex - Retrieving Records from a type of Map<SObject, List<SObject>>

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I am using a lead map where the first id represents an Account ID and the List resembles a list of leads linked to that account such as:    `Map<id, List<Id>  > leadMap = new Map< id, List<id> >();`

My question stands as following: Knowing a Lead's Id how do I get the related Account's Id from the map. My code looks something like this, The problems is on the commented out line.

```
 for (Lead l :  leads){

       Lead newLead = new Lead(id=l.id);
        if (l.Company != null)  {           
       // newLead.Account__c  = leadMap.keySet().get(l.id);
        leads_to_update.add(newLead);
       }          
      }
```

Comment: what's you error code ? your should not new lead an assign the exist id to the new one...

Comment: The problem is that in my leadMap I have a List<id> which consists of all the leads linked to an account id. Knowing only1 lead id how do I extract the account id?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all lead id and mapping company id  in the trigger then get the company id

```
Map<string,string> LeadAccountMapping = new Map<string,string>();//key is Lead id ,Company id
for(Lead l:trigger.new)
{
     LeadAccountMapping.put(l.id,l.Company);
}


//put the code you want to get the  company id
string companyid=    LeadAccountMapping.get(l.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me make sure I understand your problem.
Currently you have a map that uses the Account ID as the key to a value of a List of Lead IDs - So the map is  -> List.  Correct?

Your goal is to go from Lead ID to the Account ID.

If this is correct, then you are in a bad way, because your current structure requires a very slow, iterative search.  The correct code would look like this (replace your commented line with this code):

```
for( ID actID : leadMap.keySet() ) {
    for( ID leadID : leadMap.get( actId ) ) {
        if( newLead.id == leadID ) {
            newLead.Account__c = actId;
            leads_to_update.add(newLead);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like this solution because it requires iterating over a Map and then over each of the lists in each of the values.  It is slow.

If this isn't bulkified code, you could do a Select Query and get the Account__c value from the existing Lead by doing:

```
newLead.Account__c = [ SELECT Account__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :l.id LIMIT 1];
```

However, this relies on your code not looping over this line and hitting a governor limit.

Or you could re-write your code soe that your Map is actually:

```
Map<ID, List<Leads>> leadMap = Map<ID, List<Leads>>();
```

Then in your query where you build the map you ensure that your Lead also includes the Account__c field.

Any of these options should work, it all depends on how this code snippet in being executed and where.

Good luck!